# Cucumber for REST, writing feature file when having duplicate steps

Tags: java, testing, automation, cucumber

I am having trouble on writing the feature file as I currently wanted to have multiple step definitions on each scenario. Here is my feature file:

```
Feature: Add new voucher
   As a user I want to be able to add vouchers

Scenario Outline: Add new voucher with an invalid voucher
    Given a trip voucher <Voucher>
    When I access "/voucher" endpoint
    Then error message should be "Voucher is invalid"

Examples:
  |Voucher    |
  |ABCDEFG    |
  |1234567    |
  |invaL!Ds   |

Scenario Outline: Add a previously redeemed voucher
    Given a used voucher <Voucher>
    When I access "/voucher" endpoint
   Then error message should be "Voucher has already been used"

Examples:
  |Voucher        |
  |VALIDVOUCHER   |
```

I am working on building a REST API on Go, while learning to create integration tests on Java because the QAs are using for testing. What is the best practice here on line `When I access x endpoint`? I know it will produce the `Duplicate step definition error`. Should I change how I wrote the feature file, or there are Java tricks that I am missing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using SpecFlow + .NET at the moment at work and I have also used jBehave+Java in the past.

What you are doing is completely fine and it should not give you any errors. In fact, one of the advantage of having such Given-When-Then framework is to be able to reuse the phrases.

What you need to be careful about is to make sure that your step : When I access "/voucher" endpoint: should map to only one Java method in the steps file. so, something like:

```
@When("I access "/voucher" endpoint")
public void WhenIAccessVoucherEndpoint(){
// implementation of your step. may be make a Rest call.  
}
```

So, each time you refer to this step in your scenario file, the framework will always call this method for you. this way, you will have built basic building blocks (or pages if you are testing a website with page object pattern) and phrases. so, writing more scenarios will become easier and easier as it will be only a matter of finding the right phrases that are implemented and see if they can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, if both the steps-definition are calling the same end-point and perform the same action then it is recommended to `Re-Use` the step-definition.

As a best practice and to make the best utilization of the tool, it is always recommended to increase the reusability of the step-definitions by parameterizing the phrases and passing data as input parameters.

This benefits the code maintenance if such re-usable step-definitions are grouped under a common-step-definition class and referenced. The tool has the capability to scan all the available step-definitions and invoke the corresponding function.

If we have duplicate step-definition, there is a possibility of ending up in `"matches more than one step definition"` error message.

If you still want to maintain two different step-definition functions and have different implementations for each, then it is suggested to modify the phrases